# Resources$NotFoundException when running Roboelectric test

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I've just set up Roboelectric 3.2.2 with a new app and I have written my first simple test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest="src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
    packageName="my.pacakge.name.debug")
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void clickButton() {
        MainActivity mainActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
        String text = ((TextView)mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.text_main)).getText().toString();
        assertEquals("Should equal Hello World!", "Hello World!", text);
    }
}
```

I've followed all the set up and instructions [here](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/) and [here](http://robolectric.org/configuring/) but I am still getting this error every time I try to run the test:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x0 in packages [android, my.package.name.debug]
```

This exception occurs at the first line of the test where I am calling `setupActivity()`.

Comment: Which version of `Robolectric` do you use? I would advise to use latest and remove robolectric gradle plugin as well remove manifest and package name specification from `Config`

Comment: Did you solve your problem? if so then how?

Answer (score 2):

**It worked for me:** add `@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")`

```
@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivityTest .class) != null);
    }
}
```

**Note 1: If you are still getting the same error (happens when creating new project)**

> The Reason is related to different working directory & the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31469526/4802664

**Note 2: Using**

> Android Studio 3.0 (canary 9)
>   Gradle 4.1
>   Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha9
>   robolectric: 3.4.2

**Gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
    }
}    

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Espresso
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'

    // Robolectric
    testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin works for me when using custom RobolectricTestRunner and provide the missing system properties.

```
public class CustomRobolectricTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

  public CustomRobolectricTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
    String buildVariant = BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE + (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.isEmpty()? "" : "/" + BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
    System.setProperty("android.package", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    System.setProperty("android.manifest", "build/intermediates/manifests/full/" + buildVariant + "/AndroidManifest.xml");
    System.setProperty("android.resources", "build/intermediates/res/" + buildVariant);
    System.setProperty("android.assets", "build/intermediates/assets/" + buildVariant);
  }
}
```

Edit:
You must also use a different working directory at your unit test run configuration. Best is to change the default configuration and use $MODULE_DIR$ https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158015#c5